# Using bluejamesbond DocumentView

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the [bluejamesbond](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android) DocumentView to display a bit of justified text. I'm unable to get text to display even in the simplest of cases;

```
<com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView xmlns:ext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ext:documentView_text="test"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light" />
```

I've tried both a light and a dark background in case the default colour is one of them and hence invisible.

I've obtained the library by adding the following to the module's build.gradle;

```
compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.1'
```

The only indication of any problem is a fidelity warning from the Android Studio preview, but running on the real device (4.4.2) gives the same lack of text in each case.

I'd initially tried the more complicated [example](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android/wiki/3-%C2%B7-Examples), removing the progress bar and changing the text to just some simple inline text to get rid of other dependencies. That didn't work either, again with different backgrounds.

To rule out the possibility of something else in the layout affecting it, I've also created a new layout as follows. Again, with either a light or dark background the expected text "test" is not to be seen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView xmlns:ext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ext:documentView_text="test"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />
</LinearLayout>
```

There is a (working) demo of the library on Play Store which gives an indication that this library is of decent quality and well maintained, so how can I move on from here?

Comment: Dear Craig! Hi, Could you please elaborate on "didn't work" and "unable to get text to display"? Did you get any exceptions? Did your app crash at all?

Comment: No, there are no errors- *The only indication of any problem is a fidelity warning from the Android Studio preview*- text simply doesn't appear. When setting a contrasting background I can see the region of the window that the DocumentView is taking, which is enough for a conventional TextView to display the text, but the text does not appear in that region. I admit I've not created a seperate project (yet) to really dig into this in isolation because the benefits of this over the bog standard TextView don't warrant it- I'm at the point of wondering about obvious gotchas.